# How to clone a javascript Error into a standard object

Tags: javascript, logging, properties, runtime-error, clone

Specifically, I'd like to convert a Javascript error to an object whose properties can be listed, and hence console.logged.

```
try {
    throw new Error('418 : Blue Teapot of Death');
} catch (error) {
    for (var k in arg) { console.log('Key found: ' + k); } // Outputs nothing
}
```

**EDIT**:

Using @YeahBoy solution, there is the final solution I adopted, using [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) *pick* function :

```
var copy_with_enumerable_properties = function (obj) {
    var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj); // Include non-enumerable properties
    return _.pick(obj, props);
};

try {
    throw new Error('418 : Blue Teapot of Death');
} catch (error) {
    var error_obj = copy_with_enumerable_properties(error);
    error_obj.stack = error_obj.stack.split('\n');

    console.log(JSON.stringify(error_obj, null, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
try {
    throw new Error('418 : Blue Teapot of Death');
} catch (error) {

    var prop = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error);
    for (var k in prop) { console.log('Key found: ' + prop[k]); }
}
```

Comment: This is missing the "`name`" property for some reason, which is set to the errors' type name, e.g. "TypeError" or "Error". Because I also had issues on some browsers, I think it was a Firefox, I use `[...new Set(['name', 'message', 'stack', ...Reflect.ownKeys(myErrorObj)])]` -- the `Set` is a shortcut to ensure every key is included only once.